# How to get the Project name with the new azure-devops-extension-sdk?

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

In the [older SDK (vss-web-extension-sdk)](https://github.com/microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk) - we could use [VSS.getWebContext()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/api/vss/references/sdk_interfaces/webcontext?view=azure-devops) to get the project name and id. I coudln't find a similar method in the [newer SDK (azure-devops-extensions-sdk)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-sdk/?view=azdevops-ext-latest)

How can I get the project name with the new `azure-devops-extensions-sdk`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are samples [azure-devops-extension-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample)

Sample code:

```
import * as SDK from "azure-devops-extension-sdk";
import { CommonServiceIds, IProjectPageService } from "azure-devops-extension-api";
const projectService = await SDK.getService<IProjectPageService>(CommonServiceIds.ProjectPageService);
const project = await projectService.getProject();
```

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample/blob/master/src/Samples/Hub/OverviewTab.tsx

Answer (score 0):

In the azure-devops-extension-sdk package I have not found an interface that can meet your need, but there is an [IProjectInfo interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/iprojectinfo?view=azdevops-ext-latest) in the azure-devops-extension-api package could meet your demand.You could try it.

You could also try calling a REST API from your client-side  extension to get project name. Here is the [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) as a reference:

```
curl -u {username}[:{personalaccesstoken}] https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0
```

For details,you can refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/call-rest-api?view=azure-devops).